# Show subcategory for any chosen category

Tags: javascript, php, html, categories

I've been looking for a way to automatically display a subcategory select drop-down, only if a user selects a category. If the user doesn't select a category, the subcategory dropdown will remain hidden.

I have been looking for a way to do it by referring to online tutorials and videos but all that I've tried so far does not really work.

So please, I will like to have an assistance on how I can solve this problem. I have created a database with 2 tables:
category: catId,catName and
subcategory: subcatId,catId,subcatName

and here is my html code

```
<div class="row required">
    <label for="category_level_1">Category</label>                        
    <div class="column">
        <select id="Category" name="category" required="required" data-parsley-required-message="Please select a Category." data-level="0">
            <option value="">Select Category</option>
            <?php
                $getCategory = $category->getAllCat();
                if($getCategory){
                    while($result = $getCategory->fetch_assoc()){
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $result['catId']; ?>"><?php echo $result['catName']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </select>                          
    </div>
</div>

<div id="Subcategory" class="row hidden" >
    <label for="subcategory">Subcategory</label>                           
    <div class="column">
        <select id="Subcategory" name="subcategory" required="required" data-parsley-required-message="Please select a subcategory." data-level="1">
            <option value="">Select sub-category</option>
        </select>                            
    </div>
</div>
```

[Category Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVbAb.png)

[Subcategory Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxubf.png)

So any suggestions on how I can code it using php and javascript? I am totally new to php and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I have found it while I need to implement dependable dropdown.[(fiddle demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/8asDM/79/)

You can change design and logic as per your need.

**Tip :** Get category and subcategory in this format :

```
$cat = array(['t'] => array('t1', 't2', 't3'), ['x'] => array('x1', 'x2', 'x3'));
```

**Controller:**

```
$cat = $this->model_name->getCat();
 $final = [];
        foreach ($cat as $value) {
            $final[$value['catName']][] = array('name' => $value['subcatName'], 'key' => $value['subcatId']);
        }
```

**Model:** I have assumed category table name as `cat` and sub category as `sub_cat`, you can replace it with your table name.

```
function getCat() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('cat a');
        $this->db->join('sub_cat b', 'a.catId = b.catId');
        $result = $this->db->get();
        $cat = $result->result_array();
        $final = [];
        foreach ($cat as $value) {
            $final[$value['catName']][] = array('name' => $value['subcatName'], 'key' => $value['subcatId']);
        }
}
```

**View :**

```
echo "<select class="dependent" name="products" multiple>";
foreach ($final as $catName => $sub) {
            echo  '<optgroup label="'.$catName.'">'.'<bR>';
            foreach ($sub as $value) {
                echo  '<option value="'. $value['key'] .'">'. $value['name'] .'</option>';
            }

        }
echo "</select>";
```

You can loop through this and make dynamic dropdown.

**jQuery Code :**

```
$(function () {
    $("select.dependent").each(function (i, sel) {
        var original = $(this).clone(),
            dependent = $("<select></select>").attr({
                name: this.name
            }).insertAfter(this)
            this.name = "categories_" + this.name

            $("optgroup", this).replaceWith(function () {
                return "<option>" + this.label + "</option>"
            })
            $("option:first",this).prop("selected",true)
            $(this).removeAttr("multiple").on("change", function () {
                var cat = $(this).val()
                dependent.html(original.children("[label='" + cat + "']").html())
            }).change()
            console.log(this)
    })
})
```

**HTML Code :**

```
  <select class="dependent" name="products" multiple>
        <optgroup label="C1">
            <option>P1A</option>
            <option>P1B</option>
            <option>P1C</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="C2">
            <option>P2A</option>
            <option>P2B</option>
            <option>P2C</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="C3">
            <option>P3A</option>
            <option>P3B</option>
            <option>P3C</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
```

Comment: I saw the demo it looks good. But how can I now retrieve the information from the database using this same code?

Comment: I can help you with that if you show me your table structure.

Comment: I have two tables. first table is category: catId,catName and second table is subcategory: subcatId,catId,subcatName

Comment: thats good, edit question and share structure of those tables.

Comment: I added images of my category and subcategory tables

Comment: I checked it. It seems working but very confusing since im just a beginner. But thank you for the help